# Django-rest-framework @detail_route for specific url

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I'm using `Django-rest-framework==3.3.2` and `Django==1.8.8`. I have a simple `GenericView`

```
from rest_framework import generics
from rest_framework.decorators import detail_route

class MyApiView(generics.RetrieveAPIView):
    serializer = MySerializer
    def get(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MyApiView, self).get(*args, **kwargs)

    @detail_route(methods=['post'])
    def custom_action(self, request)
        # do something important
        return Response()
```

This works fine if I use the `router` that django-rest-framework offers, however I'm creating all my urls manually and would like to do the same with the `detail_route`.

I wonder if it's possible for me to do something like this:

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, url
from myapi import views
urlpatterns = patterns(
    '',
    url(r'^my-api/$', views.MyApiView.as_view()),
    url(r'^my-api/action$', views.MyApiView.custom_action.as_view()),
```

)

Of course this second url doesn't work. It's just an example of what I would like to do.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As [per the example from the Viewsets docs](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/viewsets/#example), you can extract individual methods into views:

```
custom_action_view = views.MyApiView.as_view({"post": "custom_action"})
```

You're then free to route this as normal:

```
urlpatterns = [
  url(r'^my-api/action$', custom_action_view),
]
```

I hope that helps.