# Django Rest Framework: @detail_route and @list_route with same name

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have a DRF ViewSet and would like to provide a detail and list routes with the same name:

```
class MyViewSet(ViewSet):
    # ...

    @detail_route(['post'])
    def do_stuff(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        pass

    @list_route(['post'])
    def do_stuff(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        pass
```

This obviously doesn't work, as the `list_route` will just overwrite the `detail_route`.

Is there a simple way to provide both routes without [manually messing up with the urls](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35554859/3185053)?

Comment: short response: no, sorry.

Comment: If you want a list view and a detail view with the same name, it would make sense to create a separate viewset for that.

Comment: @HåkenLid, can you re-post this as an answer with an example?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm not sure if this's what are you looking for, you can set the same url path name for both:

```
class MyViewSet(ViewSet):
    # ...

    @detail_route(['post'], url_path='do_stuff')
    def do_stuff_detail(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        pass

    @list_route(['post'], url_path='do_stuff')
    def do_stuff_list(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        pass
```

In the first one, the url will be ../"id"/do_stuff and, in the second one, ../do_stuff

Comment: Thanks! Requires DRF >= 1.8, otherwise you get an `received an invalid keyword 'url_path'`